# addEventListener() not responding

Tags: javascript

I have written a small program to pop up an alert on click of a button using an addEventListener() . PFB the code below:

html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>name alert</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input id="p" type="button" value="alert">
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript file

```
document.getElementById("p").addEventListener("click",greet,true);

function greet(){
  alert("hello there !");
}
```

I dont get a pop up screen this way both the files are in the same folder btw.

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/c0sLjy2t/. Maybe the source of javascript is wrong?!

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?  Is the script tag before the html?

Comment: Check the console, see the error. The script will be executed before DOM is constructed and `p` element appears in it, therefore `getElementById` call just returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`test.js` loads and executes before the DOM is loaded. So, at that point `#p` returns null. Try listening to `onload` event, and add click event.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 
 document.getElementById("p").addEventListener("click",greet,true);
    
});

// global scope  
function greet(){
   alert("hello there !");
}
```

```html
<input id="p" type="button" value="alert">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

just before

```
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the addEventListener inside a function that is called on the load event. As the page is being created it will run the javascript as it comes to it. If it hasn't created the HTML yet, when the addEventListener runs it won't find the 'p' element and it will give you an error.

You can also move the javascript to be after the html, but it's more organized to put it in something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', 'function(){pageload()}', false)

function pageload()
{
    document.getElementById("p").addEventListener("click",greet,true);
}
</script>
```